# Makegood in Eclipse says "The main script is not found"

Tags: eclipse, phpunit, ubuntu-11.04, makegood

I googled this unexpected error message and there not a single result.

I am using Eclipse Helios (3.6) with [Makegood plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/makegood-1) to run PHPUnit test.

PHPUnit is working just fine.
I can also use Makegood to one test class.
But when I run all test,  Makegood refuse to do it and display

```
'Launching <currentfilename>' has encountered a problem.
The main script is not found.
```

Looks like there are some internal issue with Makegood.  I just don t know how to get started debugging this. Is this a eclipse or makegood error message? What does it mean ? Is there any log or debug mode I could use to understand what s happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've encountered this problem when executing the **Run All Test** command. Then the project has no PHP script under the specified test folders. Since the Xdebug implementation of PDT requires a PHP file, test cannot be run in such state.

To prevent this, MakeGood checks whether the project has at least a PHP file under the specified test folders, and skips a test run if the project has no PHP scripts. But even so this error is raised by any reason...

I created a issue http://redmine.piece-framework.com/issues/310 to fix this problem.

Thank you for using MakeGood.